# How to mask on elements in css?

Tags: css

I wonder how to give this kind of effect on elements in css.
I want to give this kind of effect on an element, so that users cannot access, but slightly see it.

Can you give me hints for it?

[Masking example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaYOJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `opacity` property and `:hover` pseudo-class.

```css
.box {
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.box:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1>heading</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use css opacity property.

see this:

```css
.box{
    background:#ddd;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    padding:10px;
    opacity:0.5;
}
.box:hover{
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  hi
</div>
```